# Semidirect product in inverse Galois problem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, fields, profinite-groups, galois-groups

Let $L/\mathbb{Q}$ (resp. $K/\mathbb{Q}$) be a Galois extension of rational number field $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $P$ (resp. $H$) where $P$ is a second countable pro-$p$ group and $H$ is a finite $p'$-group (i.e. the order of $H$ is prime to $p$). My question is the following:

> Let $P\rtimes H$ be a semidirect product. Is there a Galois extension $N/\mathbb{Q}$ such that
> $\text{Gal}(N/\mathbb{Q})\cong P\rtimes H $?

In the direct product case, $N$ is just the composite field $KL$. I'm interested in the following example: Let $\rho:G_{\mathbb{Q}}\to \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ be a $p$-adic representation of the absolute Galois group $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that its mod $p$ reduction $\bar \rho$ is trivial, and hence the image $P:=\text{Im}(\rho)$ is contained in $\ker(\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)\to \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$) which is a pro-$p$ group.

My understanding is the following: First of all, the answer to the question is Yes when $P$ is finite by Shafarevich's Theorem, and thus we can assume that $P$ is infinite. Then we may write $P$ as a denumerable projective limit  $P=\varprojlim P_{i}$, where the $P_{i}$'s are finite, such that
$$P\rtimes H= \varprojlim_{i}(\cdots \to P_i\rtimes H\to P_{i-1}\rtimes H\to \cdots ), $$
where the connecting homomorphisms $ P_i\rtimes H\to P_{i-1}\rtimes H$ are surjective. Now, our goal is to construct inductively an increasing family of Galois extensions $N_{i}/\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\text{Gal}(N_{i}/\mathbb{Q})=P_{i}\rtimes H$. By Shafarevich's Theorem again, for each $i$, we can find some field $N_i\supset K$ such that $\text{Gal}(N_i/\mathbb{Q})\simeq P_i\rtimes H$ and the projection $\text{Gal}(N_i/\mathbb{Q})\simeq P_i \rtimes H\to H\simeq \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) $ is just the restriction map.(Usually, there exist infinitely many such $N_i/\mathbb{Q}$.) **The key is whether we can ensure that $N_{i+1}$ contains $N_i$, and I have no idea at this point.** Perhaps this can deduced from the fact that the projection $P_{i+1}=\text{Gal}(L_{i+1}/\mathbb{Q})\to \text{Gal}(L_i/\mathbb{Q})=P_i$ is the restriction map for some $L_i\subset L_{i+1}$ by our assumption. Any comments and references would be highly appreciated.